# Blazor websocket message decoding

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a blazor server web application.

I have catched blazor's websocket messages with wireshark.

It is a binary format. Is there a tool for decoding this messages ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I good  remember the format of the Signalr communication is Messagepack.

Try something like
https://toolslick.com/conversion/data/messagepack-to-json
to decode.

Ms doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-5.0

But it's from my memory, hope is right.